# Spring boot upgrade from 1.5.22 to 2.3.4, problem with MvcEndpoint.class

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

Does anybody have experience with upgrading `Spring boot version`? Currently, I am traying to upgrade spring boot version from `1.5.22 to 2.3.4` in my project. After I made some changes in `pom.xml`, I managed to build app successfully. Now, when I try to start our app I get this error:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed
> to parse configuration class [com.rxp.apm.Main]; nested exception is
> java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource
> [org/springframework/boot/actuate/endpoint/mvc/MvcEndpoint.class]
> cannot be opened because it does not exist

and I am not sure who is looking for this `MvcEndpoint.class` and why they are looking for it on this path: `org/springframework/boot/actuate/endpoint/mvc/`. This MvcEndpoint class used to be part of `spring-boot-actuator:1.5.22.RELEASE` and this path mentioned above was valid. But, with new `spring-boot-actuator:2.3.4.RELEASE` I am not sure that this class even exists but I am sure that this path doesn’t exist anymore. I have tried to delete everything from my .m2 file, clean install, invalidate cache… but problem stays the same. Does anybody have some idea what is the problem, or where I should look next?

There are 3 pom.xml file I have in my project

```
Pom3.xml (project with the main method)
[INFO] masked line 1
[INFO] +- io.swagger.core.v3:swagger-core:jar:2.0.9:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:jar:2.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- javax.activation:javax.activation-api:jar:1.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.30:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.10.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-yaml:jar:2.11.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.26:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:jar:2.10.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.swagger.core.v3:swagger-annotations:jar:2.0.9:compile
[INFO] |  \- io.swagger.core.v3:swagger-models:jar:2.0.9:compile
[INFO] +- org.json:json:jar:20180130:compile
[INFO] +- masked line 2
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.10.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:5.3.4.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.el:javax.el-api:jar:2.2.4:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.glassfish.web:javax.el:jar:2.2.4:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-jdbc:jar:9.0.41:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-juli:jar:9.0.41:compile
[INFO] +- masked line 3
[INFO] +- masked line 4
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop:jar:2.3.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- masked line 5
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-hateoas:jar:2.3.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework.hateoas:spring-hateoas:jar:1.1.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.6:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:jar:4.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.amqp:spring-amqp:jar:1.7.14.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.2.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework:spring-jcl:jar:5.2.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:2.3.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:2.3.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:2.3.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-to-slf4j:jar:2.13.3:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  \- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.13.3:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.30:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-json:jar:2.3.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8:jar:2.11.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-parameter-names:jar:2.11.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:5.2.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:5.2.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:5.2.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc:jar:2.3.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.zaxxer:HikariCP:jar:3.4.5:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:5.2.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:jar:2.3.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure:jar:2.3.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator:jar:2.3.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- io.micrometer:micrometer-core:jar:1.5.5:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.latencyutils:LatencyUtils:jar:2.0.3:runtime
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:jar:2.3.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:5.2.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:jar:5.3.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:5.3.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:5.3.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor:jar:2.3.4.RELEASE:compile (optional)
[INFO] +- masked line 6 
[INFO] |  \- com.google.guava:guava:jar:19.0:compile
[INFO] +- com.netflix.hystrix:hystrix-core:jar:1.5.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.netflix.archaius:archaius-core:jar:0.4.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- commons-configuration:commons-configuration:jar:1.8:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.reactivex:rxjava:jar:1.3.8:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.hdrhistogram:HdrHistogram:jar:2.1.9:compile
[INFO] +- com.openpojo:openpojo:jar:0.8.3:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:jar:2.3.4.RELEASE:provided
[INFO] |  +- jakarta.annotation:jakarta.annotation-api:jar:1.3.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:9.0.38:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.glassfish:jakarta.el:jar:3.0.3:provided
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:jar:9.0.38:provided
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:jar:2.3.4.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test:jar:2.3.4.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test-autoconfigure:jar:2.3.4.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  +- jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:jar:2.3.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:jar:1.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.assertj:assertj-core:jar:1.7.0:test
[INFO] |  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest:jar:2.2:test
[INFO] |  +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:jar:5.6.2:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:jar:5.6.2:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.opentest4j:opentest4j:jar:1.2.0:test
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-commons:jar:1.6.2:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:jar:5.6.2:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:jar:5.6.2:test
[INFO] |  +- org.junit.vintage:junit-vintage-engine:jar:5.6.2:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:jar:1.1.0:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-engine:jar:1.6.2:test
[INFO] |  +- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:1.10.19:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:2.1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.mockito:mockito-junit-jupiter:jar:3.3.3:test
[INFO] |  +- org.skyscreamer:jsonassert:jar:1.5.0:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:5.2.9.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  \- org.xmlunit:xmlunit-core:jar:2.7.0:test
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:4.12:test
[INFO] |  \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:2.2:test
[INFO] +- com.github.stephenc.jcip:jcip-annotations:jar:1.0-1:test
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools:jar:2.3.4.RELEASE:compile (optional)
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:2.3.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:2.3.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-core:jar:4.1.12.1:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-xml:jar:2.10.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-jaxb-annotations:jar:2.11.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.woodstox:stax2-api:jar:4.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.fasterxml.woodstox:woodstox-core:jar:6.0.2:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.10.1:compile
[INFO] +- com.microsoft.sqlserver:mssql-jdbc:jar:7.2.1.jre8:test
[INFO] +- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.4:compile
[INFO] +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:1.3.2:compile
[INFO] +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator:jar:6.1.5.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- jakarta.validation:jakarta.validation-api:jar:2.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.4.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.5.1:compile
[INFO] +- masked line 7 [elk stack related]
[INFO] |  \- masked line 8 [validator related]
[INFO] +- masked line 9 [Logger]
[INFO] |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.30:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.30:compile
[INFO] +- masked line 10 [messaging]
[INFO] |  +- masked line 11 [rabbit]
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-amqp:jar:2.3.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.9.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.rabbitmq:http-client:jar:1.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:5.2.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.2.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-context-support:jar:4.3.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:5.2.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-messaging:jar:5.2.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.amqp:spring-rabbit:jar:2.2.11.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.rabbitmq:amqp-client:jar:5.9.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.aspectj:aspectjrt:jar:1.9.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.9.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-healthchecks:jar:4.1.12.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.retry:spring-retry:jar:1.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- masked line 12 
[INFO] |  \- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.14:compile
[INFO] +- io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:jar:2.9.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- io.springfox:springfox-spring-web:jar:2.9.2:compile
[INFO] +- io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:jar:2.9.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.swagger:swagger-annotations:jar:1.5.20:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.swagger:swagger-models:jar:1.5.20:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.springfox:springfox-spi:jar:2.9.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- io.springfox:springfox-core:jar:2.9.2:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:jar:1.10.14:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.springfox:springfox-schema:jar:2.9.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.springfox:springfox-swagger-common:jar:2.9.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.plugin:spring-plugin-core:jar:1.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.plugin:spring-plugin-metadata:jar:1.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.mapstruct:mapstruct:jar:1.2.0.Final:compile
[INFO] +- com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:jar:2.4.0:test
[INFO] |  \- net.minidev:json-smart:jar:2.3:test
[INFO] |     \- net.minidev:accessors-smart:jar:1.2:test
[INFO] |        \- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:5.0.4:test
[INFO] +- com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path-assert:jar:2.4.0:test
[INFO] |  \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:jar:2.2:test
[INFO] +- masked line 13 
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.5.12:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.4.13:compile
[INFO] +- masked line 14
[INFO] +- commons-validator:commons-validator:jar:1.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.9.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-digester:commons-digester:jar:1.8.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.2:compile
[INFO] +- net.logstash.logback:logstash-logback-encoder:jar:4.8:compile
[INFO] |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.2.3:compile
[INFO] +- net.sf.dozer:dozer:jar:5.5.1:compile
[INFO] +- info.cukes:cucumber-java:jar:1.2.5:test
[INFO] |  \- info.cukes:cucumber-core:jar:1.2.5:test
[INFO] |     +- info.cukes:cucumber-html:jar:0.2.3:test
[INFO] |     +- info.cukes:cucumber-jvm-deps:jar:1.0.5:test
[INFO] |     \- info.cukes:gherkin:jar:2.12.2:test
[INFO] +- info.cukes:cucumber-junit:jar:1.2.5:test
[INFO] +- info.cukes:cucumber-spring:jar:1.2.5:test
[INFO] +- com.jayway.restassured:rest-assured:jar:2.9.0:test
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:jar:2.5.13:test
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-xml:jar:2.5.13:test
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:jar:4.5.12:test
[INFO] |  +- org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup:tagsoup:jar:1.2.1:test
[INFO] |  +- com.jayway.restassured:json-path:jar:2.9.0:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-json:jar:2.5.13:test
[INFO] |  |  \- com.jayway.restassured:rest-assured-common:jar:2.9.0:test
[INFO] |  \- com.jayway.restassured:xml-path:jar:2.9.0:test
[INFO] +- net.sourceforge.jtds:jtds:jar:1.3.1:test
[INFO] +- com.jayway.restassured:json-schema-validator:jar:2.9.0:test
[INFO] |  \- com.github.fge:json-schema-validator:jar:2.2.6:test
[INFO] |     +- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:3.0.0:test
[INFO] |     +- com.googlecode.libphonenumber:libphonenumber:jar:6.2:test
[INFO] |     +- com.github.fge:json-schema-core:jar:1.2.5:test
[INFO] |     |  +- com.github.fge:uri-template:jar:0.9:test
[INFO] |     |  |  \- com.github.fge:msg-simple:jar:1.1:test
[INFO] |     |  |     \- com.github.fge:btf:jar:1.2:test
[INFO] |     |  +- com.github.fge:jackson-coreutils:jar:1.8:test
[INFO] |     |  \- org.mozilla:rhino:jar:1.7R4:test
[INFO] |     +- javax.mail:mailapi:jar:1.4.3:test
[INFO] |     |  \- javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1:test
[INFO] |     \- net.sf.jopt-simple:jopt-simple:jar:4.6:test
[INFO] +- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:jar:2.4.3:test
[INFO] +- masked line 15
[INFO] |  \- io.rest-assured:rest-assured:jar:3.0.0:test
[INFO] |     +- io.rest-assured:json-path:jar:3.3.0:test
[INFO] |     |  \- io.rest-assured:rest-assured-common:jar:3.3.0:test
[INFO] |     \- io.rest-assured:xml-path:jar:3.3.0:test
[INFO] |        +- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-osgi:jar:2.2.10:test
[INFO] |        \- org.apache.sling:org.apache.sling.javax.activation:jar:0.1.0:test

=================================================================================

Pom1.xml (common)
[INFO] masked line 1
[INFO] +- masked line 2
[INFO] |  +- masked line 3 [rabbit related]
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-amqp:jar:2.3.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.26:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.google.guava:guava:jar:19.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.9.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.rabbitmq:http-client:jar:1.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.5.12:compile
[INFO] |  |        \- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.4.13:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.2.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jcl:jar:5.2.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:5.2.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:5.2.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.2.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-context-support:jar:4.3.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:5.2.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:5.2.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:5.2.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:5.2.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-messaging:jar:5.2.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.amqp:spring-rabbit:jar:2.2.11.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.rabbitmq:amqp-client:jar:5.9.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework.amqp:spring-amqp:jar:1.7.14.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.aspectj:aspectjrt:jar:1.9.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.9.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-core:jar:4.1.12.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.30:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-healthchecks:jar:4.1.12.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- masked line 4 [rest utils related]
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.retry:spring-retry:jar:1.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- masked line 5 [elk stack related]
[INFO] |  +- net.logstash.logback:logstash-logback-encoder:jar:4.8:compile
[INFO] |  +- masked line 6
[INFO] |  |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.0.b2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.14:compile
[INFO] |  \- masked line 7 [validator related]
[INFO] +- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.4:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.10.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.10.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.10.1:compile
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:4.12:test
[INFO] |  \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:2.2:test
[INFO] |     \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest:jar:2.2:test
[INFO] +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator:jar:6.1.5.Final:test
[INFO] |  +- jakarta.validation:jakarta.validation-api:jar:2.0.2:test
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.4.1.Final:test
[INFO] |  \- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.5.1:test
[INFO] \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop:jar:2.3.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:2.3.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:2.3.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:2.3.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:2.3.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    |  |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-to-slf4j:jar:2.13.3:compile
[INFO]    |  |  |  \- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.13.3:compile
[INFO]    |  |  \- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.30:compile
[INFO]    |  \- jakarta.annotation:jakarta.annotation-api:jar:1.3.5:compile
[INFO]    \- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:5.2.9.RELEASE:compile

=================================================================================

Pom2.xml (conf)
[INFO] masked line 1
[INFO] +- masked line 2
[INFO] |  +- masked line 3 [messaging related]
[INFO] |  |  +- masked line 4 [rabbit]
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-amqp:jar:2.3.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.9.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.rabbitmq:http-client:jar:1.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     \- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.5.12:compile
[INFO] |  |  |        \- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.4.13:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:5.2.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.2.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-context-support:jar:4.3.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:5.2.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-messaging:jar:5.2.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.amqp:spring-rabbit:jar:2.2.11.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.rabbitmq:amqp-client:jar:5.9.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.springframework.amqp:spring-amqp:jar:1.7.14.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.aspectj:aspectjrt:jar:1.9.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.9.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-core:jar:4.1.12.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-healthchecks:jar:4.1.12.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- masked line 5 [rest related]
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework.retry:spring-retry:jar:1.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.10.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.10.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.10.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop:jar:2.3.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:5.2.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:2.3.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:2.3.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:2.3.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:2.3.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:2.3.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-to-slf4j:jar:2.13.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.13.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.30:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- jakarta.annotation:jakarta.annotation-api:jar:1.3.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.26:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-json:jar:2.3.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8:jar:2.11.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:jar:2.10.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-parameter-names:jar:2.11.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:jar:2.3.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:9.0.38:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.glassfish:jakarta.el:jar:3.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:jar:9.0.38:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:5.2.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:5.2.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:5.2.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-hateoas:jar:2.3.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.hateoas:spring-hateoas:jar:1.1.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:jar:2.3.4.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test:jar:2.3.4.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test-autoconfigure:jar:2.3.4.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  +- com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:jar:2.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- net.minidev:json-smart:jar:2.3:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- net.minidev:accessors-smart:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |        \- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:5.0.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:jar:2.3.3:test
[INFO] |  |  \- jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:jar:1.2.2:test
[INFO] |  +- org.assertj:assertj-core:jar:1.7.0:test
[INFO] |  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest:jar:2.2:test
[INFO] |  +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:jar:5.6.2:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:jar:5.6.2:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.opentest4j:opentest4j:jar:1.2.0:test
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-commons:jar:1.6.2:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:jar:5.6.2:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:jar:5.6.2:test
[INFO] |  +- org.junit.vintage:junit-vintage-engine:jar:5.6.2:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:jar:1.1.0:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-engine:jar:1.6.2:test
[INFO] |  |  \- junit:junit:jar:4.12:test
[INFO] |  +- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:1.10.19:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:2.2:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:2.1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.mockito:mockito-junit-jupiter:jar:3.3.3:test
[INFO] |  +- org.skyscreamer:jsonassert:jar:1.5.0:test
[INFO] |  |  \- com.vaadin.external.google:android-json:jar:0.0.20131108.vaadin1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.2.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jcl:jar:5.2.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:5.2.9.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  \- org.xmlunit:xmlunit-core:jar:2.7.0:test
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor:jar:2.3.4.RELEASE:compile (optional)
[INFO] +- masked line 6 [monitoring]
[INFO] |  \- com.google.guava:guava:jar:19.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc:jar:2.3.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.zaxxer:HikariCP:jar:3.4.5:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:5.2.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.6:compile
[INFO] +- org.scala-lang:scala-library:jar:2.12.6:test
[INFO] +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator:jar:6.1.5.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- jakarta.validation:jakarta.validation-api:jar:2.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.4.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.5.1:compile
[INFO] +- com.microsoft.sqlserver:mssql-jdbc:jar:7.2.1.jre8:test
[INFO] +- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.4:compile
[INFO] +- masked line 7 [elk stack related]
[INFO] |  +- net.logstash.logback:logstash-logback-encoder:jar:4.8:compile
[INFO] |  \- masked line 8 [validator related]
[INFO] +- org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:jar:4.1:compile
[INFO] +- io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:jar:2.9.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- io.springfox:springfox-spring-web:jar:2.9.2:compile
[INFO] +- io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:jar:2.9.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.swagger:swagger-annotations:jar:1.5.20:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.swagger:swagger-models:jar:1.5.20:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.springfox:springfox-spi:jar:2.9.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- io.springfox:springfox-core:jar:2.9.2:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:jar:1.10.14:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.springfox:springfox-schema:jar:2.9.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.springfox:springfox-swagger-common:jar:2.9.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.30:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.plugin:spring-plugin-core:jar:1.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.plugin:spring-plugin-metadata:jar:1.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.mapstruct:mapstruct:jar:1.2.0.Final:compile
[INFO] \- masked line 4 [rest utils related]
[INFO]    +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.2.3:compile
[INFO]    |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.2.3:compile
[INFO]    +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO]    |  \- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.0.b2:compile
[INFO]    \- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.14:compile
```

Comment: 99% chance that there are different (incompatible) versions of Spring in the classpath. Please post your `pom.xml` (or `build.gradle`). If you have some unusual beans/configurations, please post them too.

Comment: I would suggest upgrading from 1.5.x to 2.0.x, then to 2.3.x: My learnings: https://gist.github.com/dineshbhagat/0aa4ee8453e897b33e2da9319ebbc717

Comment: I cannot share my pom.xml :/ And is multi modular project so it very hard to find proper parts of different pom.xml that I can share.

Comment: you can build the dependency graph (`mvn dependency:tree`) and post it here instead (remove or mask private libs if needed)

Comment: Yeah, thanks on suggestion.